# Should I set foreign keys in Cassandra tables?

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, cassandra-3.0

I am new to Cassandra and coming from relational background. I learned Cassandra does not support JOINs hence no concept of foreign keys. Suppose I have two tables:

**Users**

- id
- name

**Cities**

- id
- name

In RDBMS world I should pass `city_id` into `users` table. Since there is no concept of joins and you are allowed to duplicate data, is it still work passing `city_id` into `users` table while I can create a table `users_by_cities`?

Answer (score 3):

The main Cassandra concept is that you design tables based off of your queries (as writes to the table have no restrictions). The design is based off of the query filters. An application that queries a table by some ID is somewhat unnatural as the CITY_ID could be any value and typically is unknown (unless you ran a prior query to get it). Something more natural may be CITY_NAME. Anyway, assuming there are no indexes on the table (which are mere tables themselves), there are rules in Cassandra regarding the filters you provide and the table design, mainly that, at a minimum, one of the filters MUST be the partition key. The partition key helps direct cassandra to the correct node for the data (which is how the reads are optimized). If none of your filters are the partition key, you'll get an error (unless you use ALLOW FILTERING, which is a no-no). The other filters, if there are any, must be the clustering columns (you can't have a filter that is neither the partition key nor the clustering columns - again, unless you use ALLOW FILTERING).

These restrictions, coming from the RDBMS world, are unnatural and hard to adjust to, and because of them, you may have to duplicate data into very similar structures (maybe the only difference is the partition keys and clustering columns). For the most part, it is up to the application to manipulate each structure when changes occur, and the application must know which table to query based off of the filters provided. All of these are considered painful coming from a relational world (where you can do whatever you want to one structure). These "constraints" need to be weighed against the reasons why you chose Cassandra for your storage engine.

Hope this helps.

-Jim